# jQuery option:contains

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am running into a issue with the following line of code:

```
$(this option:contains(o.value)).attr("selected","selected");
```

It is returning a "missing ) after argument list" error. I know this typically has to do with unescaped or missing quotes so I tried several different ways:

```
$(this option:contains(\'+o.value+\')).attr("selected","selected");
```

...but with no luck. Any ideas what I am missing here? The REALLY strange thing is that thi line of code actually executes and selects what it is supposed to, it is just throwing the JS error.

Happy new year!

Answer (score 5):

You probably want:

```
$(this).find("option:contains('" + o.value + "')")
```

or

```
$("option:contains('" + o.value + "')", this)
```

(assuming `o` is some object), but your original code is not even valid JavaScript.

*Happy New Year to you too!*

Comment: The code provided does evaluate without error, but doesn't actually select what it is supposed to (or anything).  $(this).find("option:contains('" + o.value + "')").attr("selected","selected");  So very strange!

Comment: @Nate: Maybe you can show your HTML? And what values does `o.value` have?

Comment: You can take a look at my js and json output here: http://pastebin.com/tgts0RRs Line 42/43 in pastebin is the line in question...  Thanks again

Comment: @Nate: Mmh. You really should use `this` too (otherwise the selector will look for all option elements in the page), but that should not be a problem. Make sure that `o.value` is really string that is present in the options and als note that `contains` is case sensitive. There is not much else I can say. `:contains` itself definitely works ;)